# Casual response to "What time is it?"

Tags: словосполучення, non-native-speaker, розмовна-українська

When asked *Котра година?* (what time is it?), the only way I’ve found to reply is by way of a formal 24 hour format.  For example:

It’s 9:45 PM
*Котра зараз година?*

*Зараз,  двадцять перша  година,  сорок  п'ять хвилин.*

Hours are designated by ordinal numbers in the nominative, feminine, singular form, while minutes take a cardinal number in the nominative, feminine, plural form.

My question is, is there a more casually acceptable way of giving the time, like maybe just saying

*дев'ять, сорок п'ять?*

And what about shortcuts, like “quarter to ten”?

Comment: The first form, I would say, is more official and used mostly on radio or TV.
As you guessed, second form is more casual and is acceptable.
Third form “quarter to ten” or “quarter past ten” has its equivalent in Ukrainian - "за чверть на десяту" чи "чверть по десятій"

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is a casual way to tell time in Ukrainian.

**General pattern**

Native speakers simply omit words "година" and "хвилина". In most cases you'll be fine, if you stick to this pattern.

Based on your example for 9:45, you could just say "дев'ята сорок п'ять". Please mind the feminine gender of the word "дев'ята", as it is related to a feminine-gender word "година". However, you may hear people waiving this rule and saying gender-neutral numbers for hours, like "дев'ять". This is incorrect, although common.

**Shortcuts**

*9:00*

- "дев'ята" ("ninth"), or "дев'ять" ("nine"), the latter being incorrect, but widely used

*9:15*

Native speakers would say something like:

- "чверть десятої" ("quarter of tenth")
- "п'ятнадцять хвилин десятої" ("fifteen minutes of tenth")
- "п'ятнадцять на десяту" ("quarter of the tenth")
- "чверть по дев'ятій" ("quarter after nine")
- "п'ятнадцять по дев'ятій" ("fifteen after nine")
- "п'ятнадцять хвилин по дев'ятій" ("fifteen minutes after nine")

*9:30*

- "половина десятої" ("half of tenth")
- "пів на десяту" ("half to ten"), or "пів десятої" ("half of tenth"), the latter again being incorrect, but widely used

*9:45*

- "чверть до десятої" ("quarter to ten")
- "за чверть десята" ("tenth [hour comes] in a quarter")
- a colloquial "без п'ятнадцяти десята" ("ten without fifteen"), which is incorrect, but popular.

*AM/PM*

- AM - the word "ранку" ("of morning") added to the end of the phrase, like "дев'ята сорок п'ять ранку"
- PM - the word "вечора" ("of evening") added to the end of the phrase, like "дев'ята сорок п'ять вечора"

Comment: Thank you! But just to make sure - is it really true that "чверть десятої" and "чверть по дев'ятій" mean the same time (9:15) even though one of them mentions 10 and one mentions 9?  Why is that? It seems really easy to get them confused...

Comment: "Чверть десятої" essentially means you have full nine hours and 1/4 of the upcoming tenth hour. "Чверть по дев'ятій" literally is "1/4 of an hour has passed after full nine hours". So both mean 9:15. The difference is which hour is used as a base - a past one or the upcoming one. And I agree, I have to think twice myself when hearing this form :)

Comment: Fascinating! Both of those separately make sense, but having both in one language is kind of a lot... :)  Are they mostly used in different regions or by different generations or anything like that?

Comment: I have no such breakdown, unfortunately. My gut feeling is that "чверть по дев'ятій" is probably more in use in the West. This form is not very common anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I can add to Andrii's comment that native speakers often use 12-hour time omitting part of a day.

For example (omited part in "[]"): **шоста година [вечора]** (*It's 6 o'clock [in the evening]*)

You can use this form when there's no need to specify if it's am or pm.

Answer (score 3):

Українською мовою годину завжди вказуємо  **порядковим числівником**, тобто таким, який відповідає на питання "**котра?**"

*Друга година, десята година...*

А хвилини вказуємо **кількісним числівником** (відповідає на питання "**скільки?**")

*Десять хвилин, двадцять хвилин..*

[image: час українською]

- 10:00

  - десята година
  - **рівно** десята година
  - десята година **рівно**
- 10:10

  - десята година десять хвилин
  - десять хвилин **по** десятій
  - десять хвилин **на** одинадцяту
- 10:15

  - Десята година п'ятнадцять хвилин
  - п'ятнадцять хвилин **по** десятій
  - чверть **по** десятій
  - п'ятнадцять  хвилин **на** одинадцяту
  - чверть **на** одинадцяту
- 10:30

  - Десята година тридцять хвилин
  - пів **на** одинадцяту
- 10:40

  - Десята година сорок хвилин
  - **за** двадцять одинадцята
  - двадцять хвилин **до** одинадцятої
- 10:45

  - Десята година сорок п'ять хвилин
  - **за** п'ятнадцять хвилин одинадцята
  - **за** чверть одинадцята
  - п'ятнадцять хвилин **до** одинадцятої
  - чверть **до** одинадцятої

Пояснення взято [звідси](https://dolzhanska.blogspot.com/2016/01/blog-post_11.html).

**AM/PM** передається додаванням слів **ранку/вечора**, якщо час доби незрозумілий з контексту

> Була за чверть десята **вечора**, тобто 9:45 PM.

Comment: -1: the question was asked from the perspective of an English speaker, so both the answer and its references must be either in English or translated within the answer. Otherwise, it is merely useless for the OP.

Comment: А як сказати 00:01? Нульова година одна хвилина?

Comment: @user2513149, так само: хвилина на першу, хвилина по півночі. Схоже питання стосувалося саме другого варіанту. [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%86%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%96) погоджується.